# One year anniversary contest

Tags: discussion, contest

I know that some sites, such as Super Users, have had [contests](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/super-user-1-year-anniversary-super-contest/) around their 1 year anniversary. Perhaps if we start now, we could talk a few companies into pitching in some cool photography related things to do a similar competition for when we hit our one year mark, which so far as I can tell is in about 4 months. Anyone have any ins with camera manufactures? Think we could make this happen?

Comment: It appears that @Jeff Atwood presided over the SU thing, which would seem to indicate that the contest(s) were taken on 'above' the level of the SU community by official SE people. Maybe it would make sense to see what (if anything) is already in the works, and see how we can support it from there? Just a thought...

Comment: Hmmm... Might be interesting, but at least if we show we are interested in such a thing, it might attract his attention. Hmmm...

Comment: I'm quite certain we could talk SmugMug into pitching a year's pro membership in. :)

Comment: If we want to follow the same format as SU, we'd be wanting *four* pro memberships to give away... One for each week of the month. :-)

Comment: Well, we've got 5 months to twist their proverbial arms - the private beta started 15th July 2010; public beta was a week later on the 22nd, but the site didn't launch "properly" until November 2010.

Comment: I think 1 year from the beta should be about right.

Comment: I like it, it seems like a great idea.

Answer (score 5):

Two bits of advice based on the Super User contest:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/super-user-1-year-anniversary-super-contest/

1. Contests are a great idea but they're very labor intensive. If you can spread the "judging" across the community it will scale better. Also, keep it simple!
2. You also need to be careful that you're incentivizing the actual things you want your fellow community members to do. This is surprisingly easy to get wrong, so be careful.

Comment: Jeff, would there be a way to, say, allow all members of a certain reputation to vote on a particular issue? If that were possible, it'd certainly make judging much easier, but I know it would involve at least some work at SE.

Comment: Just curious, do you feel like you guys 'got it right' (in terms of incentivizing the right things) with the SU contest?

Comment: Can we get stats somehow of how many active users SU had at their 7 month and 1 year mark?  So that we can judge appropriateness of this site.

Comment: Also curious as to whether my impression that it was more run by you than the SU mods is correct or not?